# Добавление тестовых пользователей для аутентификации в памяти

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Как добавить тестовых пользователей для аутентификации без базы данных?
Что-то вроде user\user, admin\admin.
Что бы эти данные хранились где-нибудь в куках или памяти, пока приложение выполняется. Но не в базе данных.

Comment: Ответ практически полностью зависит от того как у вас организовано приложение. Если у вас есть сервис проверки авторизации/выдачи сессии, наверняка в нём есть другие сервисы, например сверки авторизационных данных. В рамках вашего вопроса, лично я бы сделал заглушку именно там. Но, если не следовать вашему требованию, имхо, проще создать временную базу и таки завести в ней ваших user и admin.

Comment: Но, если у вас вообще не подрузомевается базы данных как таковой, можно ограничиться элементарным файликом со списком пользователей и админов... на худой конец, создать класс-фабрику, где будут генериться ваши виртуальные сущности пользователей и админов

Comment: @test123, Приложение практически пустое, нужно сделать хранение пользователей именно в памяти, не в базе, не в файлике. В памяти или в куках.... Прорыл весь интернет везде примеры с базой данных.

Comment: тогда ваш вопрос из разряда вопросов "начинающих". Неужели не получается организовать коллекцию с виртуальными пользователями? Обычный класс, внутри обычная коллекция (можно даже Dictionary, в качестве ключа, например - логин вашего пользователя/админа) - и общая класс-модель для виртуального пользователя, с полями "логин", "пароль", "роль". Это элементарный вариант. Проще придумать не смогу...

Comment: @test123 коллекцию придумать не проблема, как и куда эти данные добавить нужно? Допустим, я хочу хранить свои данные в куках

Comment: В коллекцию, ясное дело о_О. Вас смущают сессии? или сами пользователи? Есть коллекция сессий, есть коллекция пользователей. Каждому пользователю сопоставляем сессию. У сессии есть куки. По кукам можно получить сессию, с сессии получить пользователя. Вроде всё логично... Или я не правильно понимаю вопроса

Comment: >>Допустим, я хочу хранить свои данные в куках<< Если я не ошибаюсь, куки представляют собой короткий ключ-код, который необходим для получения указателя на сессию. Записать в них что то нельзя - значит нужно записать это что то в сессию. Но, я не веб программист, и могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 0):

Попытаюсь ответить, поправьте если я не понял вопроса.
Енум для роли:

```
enum ROLE { USER, ADMIN };
```

Модель пользователя:

```
public class User {

    private string login;
    private string password;
    private ROLE role;

    public User(string login, string password, ROLE role){
        this.login=login;
        this.password=password;
        this.role=role;
    }

    public string Login {
        get {
            return this.login;
        }
        set {
            this.login = value;
        }
    }

    public string Password{
        get {
            return this.password;
        }
        set {
            this.password = value;
        }
    }

    public ROLE Role{
        get {
            return this.role;
        }
        set {
            this.role = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Далее, ваша виртуальная фабрика пользователей:

```
public class UserFactory {

    private static UserFactory instance;
    private Dictionary<string,User> users = new Dictionary<string,User>();

    public static UserFactory getInstance(){ // если вам не нужна ленивая инициализация, перенесите содержимое конструктора фабрики в статик конструктор
        if(instance==null){
            instance = new UserFactory();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public UserFactory(){ // конструктор фабрики
        users.Add(new User("user","user",ROLE.USER));
        users.Add(new User("admin","admin",ROLE.ADMIN));
    }

    public User tryFindUser(string login) {
        User user = null;
        users.TryGetValue(login, out user); // ищем пользователя по логину
        return user; // возвращаем пользователя
    }

}
```

И вот пример как эту виртуальную базу использовать:

```
User user = UserFactory.getInstance().tryFindUser("user");
User notFoundUser = UserFactory.getInstance().tryFindUser("user_test");
User admin = UserFactory.getInstance().tryFindUser("admin");
```

Так же, легко можно узнать пароли этих пользователей и провести сверку:

```
User user = ...
if(user!=null && user.Password==yourPassword){
    // ... Пользователь прошёл авторизацию
}
```

Comment: Ты не понял, мне нужно, что бы на момент запуска приложения, когда я буду пытаться залогиниться у меня уже были бы какие-то тестовые данные, и что бы я смог с ними залогиниться... Вопрос в том как и где эти тестовые данные добавлять в asp.net core

Comment: @Pyrejkee Так создайте сервис https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/2.19.php И в нём будет вышеуказанный код. Когда попытаетесь использовать этот сервис - данные в нём уже будут.